# Android xml response saying utf8 and conversion errors

Tags: android, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am sending parameters to a php script on a server through a url and am getting back an xml response. I have made sure to encode all the parameters in my url into utf8 as well.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

return entityResponse;
```

What's happening is whenever the xml returns for this one specific script I get this as a response.

```
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMElement::setAttribute() [<a href='domelement.setattribute'>domelement.setattribute</a>]: string is not in UTF-8 in <b>(server_address)/getmessagesandroidc.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::saveXML() [<a href='domdocument.savexml'>domdocument.savexml</a>]: output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xF0 0x9F 0x91 0x22 in <b>(server_address)/getmessagesandroidc.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<loginbrrr><loginbrrr...
```

Here's where I'm confused. The specific line it refers to in the php script is getting a list of user posted messages which are all utf8 format.

I have narrowed down the problem though. The script actually works when I limit the number of messages returned to 25. But if I increase the amount to 26 or higher the script immediately gives me this error. I've already tried changing message 26 to determine if it was the message causing the error but it wasn't so I'm almost certain it has something to do with the length of messages.

I have plenty of other scripts running in my app as well, some of which return even longer xml responses than this one. So I am confused as well as why the length would give me these specific errors.

When I try to parse the xml string I get the log error

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element allowed
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.insertChildAt(DocumentImpl.java:421)
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.appendChild(InnerNodeImpl.java:52)
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:306)
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:128)
        at com.packagename.XmlValues.getDomElement(XmlValues.java:72)
```

My code at XMLValues ending at line 72 is

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
doc = db.parse(is);      //line 72
```

The 'xml' variable is the entity response returned from the code above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been working on this for a few days.

Edit: Here's the script as well.

```
<?php
$login = $_GET["frcode"];

$iter = "Nationals";

$aj = "localhost";
$bj = "...";
$username_Database = "...";
$password_Database = "...";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$aj;dbname=$bj", $username_Database,     $password_Database);
$sql = 'SELECT frcode, snam, autoinc, importantz, messagez, da, mont, yea,  comit FROM chatstream WHERE frcode = ? AND length(messagez) > 0 ORDER BY autoinc DESC';
$params = array( $login );
$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$q->execute( $params );
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$r = $doc->createElement("loginbrrr" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );
foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
     $e = $doc->createElement( "loginbrrr" );
     $e->setAttribute( 'snam', $row['snam'] );
     $e->setAttribute( 'messagez', $row['messagez'] );
     $e->setAttribute( 'frcode', $row['frcode'] );
     $e->setAttribute( 'importantz', $row['importantz'] );
     $e->setAttribute( 'autoinc', $row['autoinc'] );
     $e->setAttribute( 'da', $row['da'] );
     $e->setAttribute( 'mont', $row['mont'] );
     $e->setAttribute( 'yea', $row['yea'] );
     $e->setAttribute( 'comit', $row['comit'] );

     $r->appendChild( $e );
```

}
print $doc->saveXML();

?>

This is the included script.

Comment: You are not showing your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to put utf8_encode ( $variable ) around each variable in the php script and it worked.